# Idea maven project resolve wrong dependency version

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I have a springboot project and I use Maven as my build tool. I have a dependency in my root pom.xml file as below:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch.version}</version>
        <!-- elasticsearch.version is 7.10.0 in my project -->
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In my child pom.xml file, I have the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I click Idea button to find the version of elasticsearch-rest-client,[image] it jumps to a file named 'spring-boot-dependencies-2.1.3.RELEASE.pom', and the version of this dependency is 6.4.3, which is not what I expected.

Then I use the command `mvn dependency:tree -U` to find the dependency tree, and it shows the version of elasticsearch-rest-client is 7.10.0, which is correct. And also, there is no 2.1.3 springboot version in my project.

I don't know why Idea resolves the wrong version of this dependency, and how to fix it.

------ Following UPDATE DEC 10  ---------

Since the above content is from my company's project, I have decided to use a simpler and easily reproducible example below to illustrate the issue.
First, let's look at the content of the pom.xml file:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.13</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In the pom.xml file of spring-boot-dependencies version 2.7.3, the version of httpcore is 4.4.15. However, in my project, I have imported httpcore version 4.4.13.

Next, let's consider the content of a sub-module, which is very simple:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run 'mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose', the result shows version 4.4.13. But when I use IntelliJ IDEA, the result is different:
[image: IDEA RESULT]

Comment: if you are using  [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html) run  `dependency:purge-local-repository` and in IDEA reimport  `Project > [your project name] > right click > Maven > Reimport`

Comment: Please show your full pom file... Do you use the spring boot parent?

Comment: @ArunDuraisamy I ran `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` and reloaded all maven projects, still not working for me.

Comment: @khmarbaise  I am so sorry I cannot offer you the full pom file because it is a huge, complex, and my company's project. 
This project does use springboot parent, but my point is when I use 'mvn dependency:tree' to check the dependency tree, the `elasticsearch-rest-client` version is 7.10.0 which is correct, but IDEA shows the `elasticsearch-rest-client` version is controlled by springboot parent, which is 6.4.3, I want know the reason and how to fix it.

Comment: @chenlanping this is due to Transitive Dependency.  run the `mvn dependency:tree`  and exclude elasticsearch-rest-client from the dependency `<dependency>
 <groupId>..</groupId>
 <artifactId>..</artifactId>
 <version>...</version>
 <exclusions>
  <exclusion>
   <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
     <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
 </exclusions>
</dependency>`

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing your Project's exact structure. Where does 'spring-boot-dependencies' come from - your root Project or Child? Is it added to dependencyManagement there? Also, when you run mvn dependency:tree, do you run it in the context  of your root Project or Child? You may want to take a look at IDEA's Dependency Analyzer - might give you more info on where this comes from.